# Exit loop in Fortran MPI

Tags: loops, fortran, mpi, exit

I would like to ask about how to exit a loop in Fortran when using MPI with a condition sent by the master processor of rank = 0.

Actually I'm doing this as below. But every processes is stuck with the loop and the calculation does not end as expected. Do you know what I'm missing ?

```
loop: do i = 1, N
        if (rank == 0) then
            [master processor works]
        end if
        MPI_BCAST some value "dE" to every other processes
        if (dE < error) then
           exit loop
        end if
      end do loop
```

Comment: Welcome, please read [ask] and [mcve], we need your actual code.

Comment: as long as all ranks use the same value for `error`, the pseudo code is fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I have figured out what went wrong. The idea in pseudo code is fine, but in the MPI_BCAST, I must use MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION rather than MPI_REAL.